# Show total of only visible cells in gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In my gridview, I merged few columns and wanted to show their sum in footer. In my first image, I show the grid before cell merge so the total is of all 6 records but, in second image, the grid is after cell merging and still showing the same total. What I want is to show total of only visible records not of hidden cells.

Image 1 Before cell merge
[image: 1]

Image 2 After cell merge

[image: 2]

Comment: is pagination being used in gridview ?

Comment: can u show sum code? are you merging at client side on server side event?

Comment: if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            mergegrid();
            Label gross = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltotalamount");
            tgross += double.Parse(gross.Text);
}
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            Label sgross = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblAmount");
            sgross.Text = tgross.ToString();
}

Comment: yes later on i"ll add the pagination o gridview also